# The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseApp'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase Authentication for user login but getting this error message for FirebaseApp Configure Method.
below is my code.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import '../Questions.dart';

class Tasks extends StatefulWidget {
  Tasks({this.uid: ""});
  final String uid;
  @override
  TasksState createState() => TasksState(uid);
}

class TasksState extends State<Tasks> {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  bool timeUp = true;
  TasksState(this.userId);

  Map<String, dynamic> identifiers = Map.from({
    "answered": false,
    "value": false,
    "notDone1": true,
    "notDone2": true,
    "defNumber": -1,
    "hour": null
  });
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String userId;
  DocumentReference ansRef;

  Future<void> configure() async {
    final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
        name: 'companionbeta',
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '*******************************',
            apiKey: '********************************',
            projectID: '*******************'
));
    final FirebaseFirestore firestore = Firestore.instance();
    await firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
  }

  bool isDepressed(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    document.data.putIfAbsent("q1", document["defNumber"]);
    if (document["q1"] < 3) return true;
    return false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    configure();
    ansRef = Firestore.instance.collection("answers").document(userId);
    addData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateTime(DocumentSnapshot document) async {
    if (document["hour"] == null)
      await document.reference.updateData({"hour": now.hour});
    assert(now.hour != null);
    if (document["hour"] < 24) {
      setState(() {
        timeUp = true;
      });
      await document.reference.updateData({"hour": document["hour"] + 24});
    }
  }

  void addData() async {
    ansRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      ds.data.addAll(identifiers);
      updateTime(ds);
      isDepressed(ds);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("answers").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading..");
              DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents[0];
              Map<String, bool> check = Map.from({
                "answered": (doc["answered"] == null) ? false : true,
                "notDone1": (doc["notDone1"] == null) ? false : true,
                "notDone2": (doc["notDone2"] == null) ? false : true,
                "q1": (doc["q1"] == null) ? false : true,
              });
              return builder(context, doc, check);
            }));
  }

  Widget builder(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document,
      Map<String, bool> check) {
    return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
      (check["answered"] && timeUp && !document["answered"])
          ? askQuestion(document)
          : Container(),
      Flexible(
          child: Card(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            (check["notDone1"] &&
                    check["q1"] &&
                    isDepressed(document) &&
                    document["notDone1"])
                ? ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.people),
                    title: Text("Meet more people"),
                    subtitle: Text("uno dos tres"),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                      value: false,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (value)
                            document.reference.updateData({"notDone1": false});
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
            (check["notDone2"] &&
                    check["q1"] &&
                    isDepressed(document) &&
                    document["notDone2"])
                ? ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.library_music),
                    title: Text("Listen to tunes"),
                    subtitle: Text("uno dos tres"),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                      value: document["value"],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (value)
                            document.reference.updateData({"notDone2": false});
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
            (check["q1"] &&
                    check["notDone1"] &&
                    isDepressed(document) &&
                    !document["notDone1"])
                ? Card(
                    child: Expanded(
                    child: Text("Yay! We are happy today"),
                  ))
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
        elevation: 2.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 6.0),
      ))
    ]);
  }

  Widget askQuestion(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
            title: Text('Ready to answer a few questions?'),
            subtitle: Text('It will only take a minute'),
          ),
          ButtonTheme.bar(
            // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
            child: ButtonBar(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: const Text('Yes!'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Questions(document)));
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: const Text('Not now'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      document.reference.updateData({"answered": true});
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      elevation: 2.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    );
  }
}
```

for privacy issue's i'm removed googleID, appkey, and projectId, so ignore that.

error message.

The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseApp'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FirebaseApp` does not have a method called `configure`, you need to use `initializeApp`:

```
    final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
        name: 'companionbeta',
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '*******************************',
            apiKey: '********************************',
            projectID: '*******************'
));
```

Comment: thanks @peter-haddad for the suggestions.